# Fourier transform and signal envelope

Tags: fourier

is there any relation Fourier transform and signal envelope(time domain)? I want to find standing wave envelope function.

Answer (score 3):

What you really need to find the envelope is the Hilbert Transform.  A fair review of the method is at http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/examples/envelope-detection.html

http://kurage.nimh.nih.gov/meglab/Meg/HilbertTransform suggests that to get the Hilbert transform you can take the FFT, multiply the positive frequencies by 2, zero the negative ones, and invert-- noting that you don't touch the zero frequency component.  The absolute value of the Hilbert transform is the envelope.

Comment: Fourier transform of a signal gives me signal envelope. ( True or False) .Thanks (sorry i don't know english)

Comment: @BizimOsman  False

Comment: @BizimOsman  Utterly False.